# Amplify sinewave to 6A

Tags: amplifier, transformer

I am trying to create a 6A, 60Hz sinewave. A 50W audio amplifier with the standard 4Ω minimum output resistance is available, but I deduce it is only able to supply an absolute maximum of 3.5A. My idea was to use a transformer on that output and increase current that way. The signal will be applied to a measurement device, meaning minimal load only. Finding the right transformer is getting me headache. What is the right way of creating such low-voltage, high-current, virtually no-load AC signal, what would you do? Cheap & easy preferred.

Comment: May I ask what is that for?

Comment: Why can't you use an ordinary mains-driven transformer? You need to provide some details about how precise this waveform must be in terms of the value of the current, the frequency, the sine shape (i.e., how much distortion), etc.

Comment: So you want to generate a 120V AC 60Hz signal with 6A and  how much line regulation error? 5%? then source impedance must be 5% of load.  Pls add details to your specs for V,I,f,Rs  ( assuming only 50Hz is avail)

Comment: If it's a 2-channel amplifier, you can parallel the channels with a low resistance (an ohm or two) from each output to the load. Much simpler than trying to find a suitable transformer.

Comment: What output voltage drive level is needed and what load impedance does it feed?

Comment: 6 A at what voltage?

Comment: "low" voltage ... presumably not critical how low.

Comment: What are you feeding the 6 ampere source into, and what are you trying to measure?

Comment: a 'no-load' AC signal? Sounds like it's not into a short circuit then. What do you need the amps for? How about specifying what the load is, what voltage it requires, what current it requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method that would optimize the load would be to buy a 50VA or better toroidal power transformer with a 14-16V secondary.

You can test-power the transformer from the mains as intended and place a few turns of wire threaded through the core. Measure the voltage induced, divide by the number of turns to determine the volts per turn.

You can then wind a secondary with your desired ratio (say 4:1) using wire capable of handling 14A. Say the volts per turn is 0.25, original secondary is 15V, and you want a 4:1 ratio (3.75V), so you would wind 3.75/0.25 = 15 turns of heavy wire (which is where you connect your load). Connect the amplifier to the original 15V secondary.

The transformed impedance is divided by the square of the turns ratio, so a 250m\$\Omega\$ ohm load will appear as 4 ohms at the amplifier with a 4:1 turns ratio. You can go as low as a single turn, which will give you very high current (potentially), but you will have to keep the resistance extremely low. In my example, the turns ratio would be 60:1 and the current could be as high as 200A but the resistance would have to be kept to 1.5m\$\Omega\$ total including the winding.

**Be sure to insulate the original primary winding connections because they will have approximately mains voltage on them at full input voltage.**

Be aware that many audio amplifiers are utterly incapable of supplying their full rated RMS power for any length of time, so you may need to do the optimization I suggest.

Note: A small nit - we don't call this amplifying because there is no power gain. You will actually lose a bit of power in the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting some ordinary power transformer to the output of the audio amp.  Let's say you have a 115 V to 12 V transformer.  Connect the 115 V primary to the audio amp output.  In theory if the transformer was ideal, you would get 9.6 times the output current from what the amp is producing.  Of course the voltage would also be lower by that same factor.

Real transformers have losses, so the voltage x current out will be less than the voltage x current in.

The transformer also has to be rated for more than the output current you want.  In the case of a power transformer, the rated output current is achievable with the intended input voltage.  However, your amp won't put out that much.  If your audio amp can drive 50 W into 8 Ω, then it is only producing 20 V.  A power transformer specified at 115 V in may not be able to produce its full rated output current with only 20 V in, even with the secondary shorted.  Over-specifying the power transformer will help.

Comment: So the questioner has an amplifier that can't power a load and you think putting a transformer inbetween will help?  This answer got a really fast upvote for that doesn't acknowledge that there is in adequate information to give a proper answer.  So if the load didn't change did the transformer turn the amplifier into a 100W amplifier?

Comment: @owg: The OP only wants high *current* out.  That's what I answered.  He seems to understand this will result in low voltage.

Comment: Well we don't know what the load is.  Let's guess it is resistive.  How did lowering the voltage increase the current?  Of course maybe it's not resistive. But that would be a reason to ask for clarification.  There have been many questions on this StackExchange that have been clearer than this that were berated by long time users here.  I can only suppose this answer is about the reputation points and in not an attempt to be helpful.

Comment: @owg: You are making up constraints the OP never specified.  I take it to mean he wants high current into essentially a short.

Comment: So you have made up the constraint that it is into a short circuit.  I already acknowledged that resistive was conjecture.  The point is the question is not complete enough to give an answer.  So I have to ask you.  Before you answered this you didn't think to yourself; I don't know this is into a short maybe this is not a good answer?  Even if your constraint is correct, what does the input to a transformer with a short on the output look like?  This answer is like a college student asking a question without even thinking about it.

Comment: @owg60 I think you are over-reacting. There is nothing wrong in taking a stab at an answer providing you explain (in the answer) what the limitations are. Clearly the OP understands that he can use a 50 watt amplifier with an output transformer so I personally, don't see your gripe.

Comment: @Andy, I see many posts from you that are thoughtful, helpful, and friendly.  My grip is having the fun taken out of this StackExchange by long time members supporting each other's bad answers.  I don't know what the OP knows.  I only know what the question says.  It says he has given much consideration to a transformer.  Now he is looking for another alternative.  This answer says to try any old transformer and gives some hobby magazine level information about transformers.  How does that get an instant upvote?

Comment: @owg: You seem to be going out of your way to find fault.  The OP wants high current.  I'm assuming this is into essentially a short, like this "measurement device" he is testing is a current transformer.  We don't know that, but it's at least as reasonable assumption as anything else at this point.  Downvote as you see fit, but there is nothing wrong with trying to answer this question.